# Command Line Argument processing in c

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

On running the below code, it stucks after displaying the `argv[0]`, `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` line.
Further flow of code is blocked at this point, can any one help why it is stopping its execution or is it entering into an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "p8log.h"
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        char* PORT;
        char* IPADDR;

        printf("Arg Count=%d\n",argc);
        printf("Arguments are=%s,%s,%s\n",argv[0],argv[1],argv[2]);

        printf("HELLO");

        PORT=argv[1],
        printf("WORLD");
        IPADDR=argv[2];

        printf("START");
        printf("port num=%s",PORT);
        printf("IP ADDR=%s",IPADDR);
        printf("END");

        /* some algorithm of calculation */

        return 0;
}
```

---

Execution

```
./file-exe 11111 127.0.0.1
```

---

Output

```
Arg Count=3

Arguments are=./file-exe,11111,127.0.0.1
```

Comment: The title is C++ but the tag is C. Which language do you use?

Comment: Apparently there is no control of flow; it is unlikely that the shown code causes an infinite loop. What is the output so far? Is the part where `END` is written to the output ever reached?

Comment: Are you passing more than two arguments? Check `argc` before accessing `argv[]`

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9696fbb4ea6277db).

Comment: What is output of execution? And what are the command line arguments you are providing?

Comment: Add `\n` to all `printf`'s. Post the input you enter, then the output you see.

Comment: For me it works fine: `$ ./a.exe 11111 127.0.0.1`
`Arg Count=3`
`Arguments are=C:\tmp\a.exe,11111,127.0.0.1`
`HELLOWORLDSTARTport num=11111IP ADDR=127.0.0.1END`

Comment: P.S. After the OP edit, crystal ball says it's stuck in the `/* some algorithm of calculation */` code that was _not_ posted.

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout);` right after `printf("END");`.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for notifying a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fflush(NULL); is good to do after any output, if you want to make sure it prints to screen.  printf is buffered, so it can get lost.

```
./a.out 11111 127.0.0.1
Arg Count=3
Arguments are=./a.out,11111,127.0.0.1
HELLO
WORLD
START
port num=11111
IP ADDR=127.0.0.1
END
```

works fine, you needed some \n to break up lines, like so..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        char* PORT;
        char* IPADDR;

        printf("Arg Count=%d\n",argc);
        printf("Arguments are=%s,%s,%s\n",argv[0],argv[1],argv[2]);

        printf("HELLO\n");

        PORT=argv[1],
        printf("WORLD\n");
        IPADDR=argv[2];

        printf("START\n");
        printf("port num=%s\n",PORT);
        printf("IP ADDR=%s\n",IPADDR);
        printf("END\n");
        fflush(NULL);
        /* some algorithm of calculation */

        return 0;
}
```